# how to calculate total hours from dict in column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, datetime

I have a df column which contains dict of hours timing
Example:

```
df['hours'][:1]
out:
         {'Monday': '0:0-0:0',
      'Tuesday': '8:0-18:30',
      'Wednesday': '8:0-18:30',
      'Thursday': '8:0-18:30',
      'Friday': '8:0-18:30',
      'Saturday': '8:0-14:0'}
```

by writing python code how can i calculate total hours in a week.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the values by using this:-
`for key,value in dict.items():`
After this have a counter variable, `counter = 0`
Then for each value, split it by `value.split('-')`

After doing this, convert the splitted list into numbers by further splitting it with ":". After this convert both of them in minutes, then subtract them.
Add this subtracted value to the counter.

You'll do this in this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dictionary, you can use a python generator expression (with help of [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for the conversion):

```
sum((b-a).total_seconds()/3600
     for v in  d.values()
     for a,b in [[pd.to_timedelta(x+':0')
                 for x in v.split('-')]]
     )
```

output: `48.0`

From a Series of dictionaries as strings:

```
def total_hours(d):
    from ast import literal_eval
    if pd.isnull(d):
        return 0
    return sum(
        (b-a).total_seconds()/3600
         for v in  literal_eval(d).values()
         for a,b in [[pd.to_timedelta(x+':0')
                     for x in v.split('-')]]
        )

df['hours'].map(total_hours)
```

Alternative using string methods:

```
(df['hours']
  .str.extractall('(?P<start>\d+:\d+)-(?P<stop>\d+:\d+)')
  .apply(lambda s: pd.to_timedelta(s+':00').dt.total_seconds().div(3600))
  .eval('stop-start').sum()
)
```

output:

```
1    48.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: HI, thank you its not a dict actually, it is an instance of column.

Comment: Can you provide an unambiguous reproducible object for clarity?

Comment: i have edited my question, can you please take a look again.

Comment: Please provide the output of `df['hours'].to_dict()`

Comment: output of df['hours][:1]    

{1: "{'Monday': '0:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '8:0-18:30', 'Wednesday': '8:0-18:30', 'Thursday': '8:0-18:30', 'Friday': '8:0-18:30', 'Saturday': '8:0-14:0'}"}

Comment: I see, not a very good format ;) Check the update

Comment: getting this error  5          for v in  literal_eval(d).values()
      6          for a,b in [[pd.to_timedelta(x+':0')
      7                      for x in v.split('-')]]
      8         )

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248256/discussion-between-malik-hamza-and-mozway).

Comment: Add `if pd.isnull(d): return 0` in the beginning of the function